# Usage of comma between two lines

Tags: punctuation, commas

I use this as the closing line in all emails to recruiters, Grammarly says the 
second one with the comma as punctuation is right, but I am not quite sure.

**Wrong according to Grammarly:** I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ and I look forward to hearing from you.

**Right according to Grammarly:** I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ, and I look forward to hearing from you.

Which of the following is the best way to use it or suggest a new line?

A: I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ, and I look forward to hearing from you.

B: I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ and look forward to hearing from you.

What is the best way to say that?

Comment: You should use a comma after _and_ when it separates two independent clauses. Since both clauses have a subject and verb ("i am" and "i look," respectively) and make sense on their own, you need a comma to separate them.

Comment: @vanderpn I have edited and added more details, can you post it detailed as an answer?

Comment: You should know that reading "as per" to mean "according to" comes across very negatively to some people. It reflects poorly on the writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct, but the first one (with the comma), provides more accuracy. It provides a way of telling the reader that the sentence is finished and there is no second subject. Consider mentioning two companies as in the following sentence:

I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ and ABC.

In other words: using the comma, means that there is no second subject to wait for. Whereas using a comma before the *and*, means that the following *and* is only means to connect two sentences.

This is the reason why decimal marks are used, because they provide more accuracy. But not using them is not a grammatical mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Both A & B are correct grammatically. Here's an explanation why:

**A** uses a comma after *and* because it joins two independent clauses; i.e.

> I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ

and

> I look forward to hearing from you

are both independent clauses because they both have a subject and a verb and make complete sense on their own.

**B** does not use a comma after *and* because there is only one clause with a compound verb; i.e.

> look forward to hearing from you

is not a complete thought by itself, so it should not be separated from the rest of the sentence by a comma.

Deciding which of these is best is more a matter of opinion. Personally, I prefer **A**, but I can't really tell you a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Purely in the context of the question, both are correct.

There is a difference between:
'I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ, and I look forward to hearing from you.' and

'I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ and look forward to hearing from you.' but in the context of the question, that's not relevant.

Further, 'I am excited about the opportunity to work at XYZ…' is strictly incorrect unless you are replying to a job offer, which clearly you are not.

What you mean there is something like 'I would be excited to have an opportunity to work at XYZ…' Is the difference clear?